# Is there any impact on changing the alpha numeric validation for Sitecore Commerce Sellable item Name Field

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is there any specific reason for having alphanumeric validation for the **Sellable item Name** field?

In our case, we need to allow products with special character Names( like product names with hyphens and percentages).

if `AlphanumericOnly_NameValidation` Validation Regex is removed from the **Sellable Item Name** Field, will there be any issue?

Our Sitecore version is 9.2

Answer (score 1):

Changing name is fine as long as it is compatible with Sitecore Item name as well since these products are displayed in the content tree. So same rule should be applied.

Don't change the ID to use hyphen, it will break the system if you add a hyphen in the sellable item id. If you look at the sellable item id, it uses hyphen as an identifier. Then there is a parsing logic that extracts the number from this field, url logic, etc

[image]

Comment: @sckautilya Thanks for your answer.
One thing i noticed is that in sitecore content tree item name is created based on **display name** and commerce product name we can see under Content section.
So i am thinking why there is a alpha numeric validation for product Name's as product name could have characters like hyphen,Percentage.

Comment: It is there to enforce certain validations, if not required, it can be changed.